# When linking ASM to C++ file, there is an access violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

To give you context over the code, this is a dot product computation of two vectors using pointer arithmetic (looping with pointers as well). I have linked it in my main.cpp but for some reason, when the function is called (in this case, my ASM file), i get an access violation error. Here are the two files. Thank you for your help!

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <windows.h> 
#include <algorithm>
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
extern "C" int dpp_pointerr(int *v, int *u, int n); //ASM FILE


 void main(void) {

const int N = 10;
static int A[10];
static int B[10];

printf("Array A: ");
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { A[i] = rand() % 10; /*printf("%d ", A[i]); */ }
printf("\n\nArray B: ");
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) { B[j] = rand() % 10;/* printf("%d ", B[j]);*/ }
printf("\n");
int result2 = dpp_pointerr(A, B, N);
printf("\nResult after POINTER dot product: %d\n", result2);

__int64 ctr1 = 0, ctr2 = 0, freq = 0;
int    acc = 0, i = 0;

if (QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&ctr1) != 0) {
    /****************CODE TO BE TIMED HERE**********************/

    //int result3= dot_product_index(A, B, N);
    int result2 = dpp_pointerr(A, B, N);
    /**********************************************************/
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&ctr2);
    cout << "Start Value: " << ctr1 << endl;
    cout << "End   Value: " << ctr2 << endl;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *)&freq);
    // freq  is number of counts per second. It approximates the CPU frequency 
    printf("QueryPerformanceCounter minimum resolution: 1/%I64u Seconds.\n", freq);
    printf("ctr2 - ctr1: %f counts.\n", ((ctr2 - ctr1) * 1.0 / 1.0));
    cout << "65536 Increments by 1 computation time: " << ((ctr2 - ctr1) * 1.0 / freq) << " seconds\n";
}
else {
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    printf("Error value = %d", dwError);
}
cout << endl;
cout << "Press ENTER to finish";
system("pause");
```

}

ASM FILE
    ; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547.0

```
    TITLE   C:\Users\Patrick\source\repos\dot_product_legit\dot_product_legit\dpp_pointerr.cpp
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat, C

PUBLIC dpp_pointerr

_TEXT   SEGMENT

_result$ = -32                      ; size = 4
_B_beg$ = -20                       ; size = 4
_A_beg$ = -8                        ; size = 4
_v$ = 8                         ; size = 4
_u$ = 12                        ; size = 4
_n$ = 16                        ; size = 4
?dpp_pointerr@@YAHPAH0H@Z:
dpp_pointerr PROC           ; dot_product_pointer, COMDAT
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 228                ; 000000e4H
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-228]
    mov ecx, 57                 ; 00000039H
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd
    mov DWORD PTR _result$[ebp], 0
; Line 11
; Line 2
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 228                ; 000000e4H
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-228]
    mov ecx, 57                 ; 00000039H
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd
; Line 5
    mov eax, 4
    imul    ecx, eax, 0
    add ecx, DWORD PTR _v$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR _A_beg$[ebp], ecx
; Line 6
    mov eax, 4
    imul    ecx, eax, 0
    add ecx, DWORD PTR _u$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR _B_beg$[ebp], ecx
; Line 8
    mov DWORD PTR _result$[ebp], 0
; Line 11
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _A_beg$[ebp]
    mov ebx, DWORD PTR _B_beg$[ebp]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _n$[ebp]
    mov edi, DWORD PTR _v$[ebp]
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [edi+ecx*4]
    mov esi, DWORD PTR _u$[ebp]
    lea esi, DWORD PTR [esi+ecx*4]
    jmp SHORT $LN4@dot_produc
$LN2@dot_produc:
    add eax, 4
    add ebx, 4
$LN4@dot_produc:
    cmp eax, edi
    jae SHORT $LN3@dot_produc
    cmp ebx, esi
    jae SHORT $LN3@dot_produc
; Line 12
    imul eax, ebx
    add DWORD PTR _result$[ebp], eax
    jmp SHORT $LN2@dot_produc
$LN3@dot_produc:
; Line 13
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _result$[ebp]
; Line 14
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
    dpp_pointerr ENDP           ; dot_product_pointer
_TEXT   ENDS

END
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it with the debugger to the point is faults? Look at the registers at that point. Likely something is amiss.

Comment: Do you really have the function prologue doubled?

Comment: @Jester : I had a hard time believing this code was the raw output of the optimizing compiler. It was almost like someone took the output and then copy and pasted something into it and then all hell broke loose lol. OP could have shown us the original CPP file he got the assembler listing from.

Comment: Performing a dot product, on a x86 without using SSE as a result of an optimizer => this peace of assembly code is maybe very old. Maybe the assembly and your compiler does not use anymore the same ABI.

Comment: Aside from the fact that it looks like you took the assembly output of the Microsoft compiler and mangled it (as described by Jester and Michael Petch), the output of the Microsoft compiler is only meant to be informational. You cannot reliably assemble it, link it into an application and get something that works.

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to mention that I took compiler generated code and tried to optimize it from the original without DPPS.

Comment: Code that uses `imul    ecx, eax, 0` is *not* a good starting-point for optimization!  That's a really bad way to set `ecx=0`.  Also, IDK why you even mention DPPS; your data is integer not `float`, and it's not 4 or less elements long (the only time DPPS is useful).  Accumulate elementwise products "vertically" inside the loop and only horizontal sum at the end.

Comment: Which instruction is faulting, and what values are in registers at the time?  Include that to make this a [mcve].  (Or better, use the debugger to debug it yourself.)